# How do I add multiple hours in php to have the total hours?

Tags: php

I'm working on a time in and time out system, just editing some codes. The format of the time being recorded is in H:i:s. The system allows the user to see their time in the office in a table. In the table, first row: we have the Date-In, Time-In, Date-Out, Time-Out and the number of hours that the employee stayed in the office. For example, Time is from 09:00:00 to 18:00:00 the hours that will be shown is 9.00 hours because I made it in decimal format. If its 09:20:00 to 18:00:00 the hours of it should be in decimal also. For example: 8.70 hours. Something like that.

Now, the table that is being shown is for the whole month. Below the table, there will be total hours that is in the format hours and mins (Ex. 77 hours and 6 mins) and also in decimal (77.10 hours). **How do I compute the total hours?**

The code below is the computation of the hours. Getting the hours of the time-in and out.

```
$n = $totalMins/60;
$whole = floor($n);      // 1
$fraction = $n - $whole;

$totalHrs += $whole;
$totalMins = round($fraction*60);
$totalMins = sprintf("%02d", $totalMins);

$elapsedDeci = round($fraction, 2);
$elapsedDeci += $totalHrs;
$elapsedDeci = number_format($elapsedDeci, 2);
$elapsed = "$elapsedDeci";
```

Comment: Add the minutes up then format it as hours and minutes when you display it. Without your code it's hard to help further.

Comment: I added the code for the hours.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your approach was, that you mixed the calculation and the formatting of your time, which made it difficult for you to contiue calculations with your results.

I would advise you to strictly seperate calculation and displayment. This way, you can calculate your times first, and then display them in a formatted manner.

By reading your code, I assume that you already have the working time of each day in form of an amount minutes at hand, for example in an array like this (for the sake of explanation and readability, let's pretend our month is only seven days):

```
$minutes_stayed = array(480, 500, 460, 503, 429, 0, 0);
```

It should be easy for you, to create some similar structure with any kind of database querying that you are doing.

Now, you should first try and format your minutes into timespans you want to work with, like hours or decimal hours. Store a single timespan like `$minutes = 480;` and perform some mathematical wizardry. Note, that I did not do any string formatting yet:

```
$formatted = array();

$formatted["hours"]   = floor($minutes/60);
$formatted["minutes"] = $minutes - $formatted["hours"]*60;
$formatted["decimal"] = $formatted["hours"] + $formatted["minutes"]/60;
```

after you did so, you are free to do whatever you want. Sum/ subtract/ print/ throw away/... the possibilities are endless.

---

Have a look at following class. It is basically a deduction of your existing code, but with a strict seperation of calculation and displayal:

```
class TimeCalculator 
{
    public static function print_as_decimal( $decimal )
    {
        echo number_format($decimal, 2, '.', '')." hours";
    }

    public static function print_as_h_and_min( $hours, $minutes )
    {
        echo $hours." hours and ".$minutes." minutes";
    }

    public static function format( $minutes )
    {
        $formatted = array();

        $formatted["hours"]   = floor($minutes/60);
        $formatted["minutes"] = $minutes - $formatted["hours"]*60;
        $formatted["decimal"] = $formatted["hours"] + $formatted["minutes"]/60;

        return $formatted;
    }
}
```

---

It should not be too hard to figure out, what each of the functions does. Using this class you have all you need to easily work with your time. Try this code:

```
$minutes_stayed = array(480, 500, 460, 503, 429, 0, 0);

foreach($minutes_stayed as $day => $time)
{
    $formatted = TimeCalculator::format($time);
    echo TimeCalculator::print_as_decimal($formatted["decimal"])." equals ";
    echo TimeCalculator::print_as_h_and_min($formatted["hours"], $formatted["minutes"])."<br />";
}

$formatted_total = TimeCalculator::format(array_sum($minutes_stayed));
echo "Total: ";
echo TimeCalculator::print_as_decimal($formatted_total["decimal"])." or ";
echo TimeCalculator::print_as_h_and_min($formatted_total["hours"], $formatted_total["minutes"])."<br />";
```

as you can see, with the right seperation of calculaton and displayal, *the only thing you actually need* to calculate the total amount of hours, is `array_sum($minutes_stayed)`.